# Primefaces Bar Chart disable all Series

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, jqplot

i have a system running with Primefaces on a Server for some Diagramms, like the Bar Chart and stuff.

My Problem is: the bar chart is full with Series so it is a little slow, but more importantly is that it is not very clear. So I wanted to have a function to unclick/disable all Series from the start and then manually enable which one I need, but I am not an expert in Javascript nor with Primefaces.

I found out that I can do something with the Extender but it turns out the show function there disables the whole chart so it doesnt render.

Does anyone already solved something like this or has a tip for me?

Comment: So i learned that you can use the Extender for this purpose, so a script with :
 this.cfg.series[0].show = false;
 this.cfg.series[1].show = false;
so the first two Series would be disabled from the start.
But I still didnt find the method to do this with a button.

Comment: start by finding out (and telling us) where the slowness comes from. Client-side, server side and servers-side narrow it down even further.

Comment: i guess the slowness comes from Client-Side, as the Bar Chart is only plotted once and then the client can do and undo things like clicking on a label so that this series is not plotted anymore, but this is only client sided so the server has nothing to do with this anymore. Thats why i search for the method to unclick all labels with a button. I found a method to unclick all from the start but thats it :
 `var s = this.cfg.series.length - 1;
 for(var i = 0; i < s ;i++){
  this.cfg.series[i].show = false;
 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i did find the solution myself. For everyone who is searching something similiar:

```
function toggleAllLabels(model) {
for(var i = 0; i < model.getElementsByClassName("jqplot-table-legend-label").length; i++){
    model.getElementsByClassName("jqplot-table-legend-label")[i].click();
    }
```

}

where model is the (Bar-)Chart Object. The idea is: you simulate a click on every label so it is triggered and disabled. The function has to be called from the page with the chart and with the argument "model" for the id of the Chart Object.